# jQuery - How to select child elements of parent?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Sorry if the title is not accurate - I couldn't figure out how to word it.

I have multiple widgets with the same class `<div class="widget"></div>` - each widget has a title, and content, structured like this:

```
<div class="widget">
    <div class="widget-title">Title</div>
    <div class="widget-content">Content Here</div>
</div>
```

The "widget-content" is hidden, and when you click on the widget-title, the content appears, and a class is applied to the widget-title, changing it to "widget-title open".  This part works find, and the widget-content opens too.

The problem is, its opening the widget content on ALL widgets. It should only open the widget-content in the specific widget where the title was clicked, not ALL of them.  I am not sure what the proper syntax is to use so it only opens the widget-content of the specific widget the user click the title on.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$('.widget').find('.widget-title').click(function() {
  $('.widget-content').show('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
  $('.widget').find('.widget-title').addClass("open");
});
```

Could someone please provide a working example?  Thanks

Comment: Post your html structure and I'll provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Too late for me too answer -.- but yeah, the concept is that you should be using jQuery's valuable '$(this)' in the click event to distinguish between different widgets, and the actual jQuery object you are clicking on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$('.widget .widget-title').click(function() {
    $(this)
        .addClass("open")
        .parent().find('.widget-content').show('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
});
```

Comment: That works fine, thank you so much for showing me, I will remember this for the future!  I thought that I might need to use the $(this) function, but I wasn't sure how!  This is perfect.

Comment: Why do you add the class open before the show? wouldn't it be better to do the add class on the callback of the show since thats the point at which it is 'open' .

Comment: Why not use 'children'? Find() is not needed in this case and will only slow down the script.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
$('.widget').find('.widget-title').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().show('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    }).addClass("open");
});
```

It opens the parent of the selected `.widget-title` element.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The user wants to show the content when the title of the widget is clicked, not the widget, which is already visible. The selector, children(), should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.widget-title').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.widget').children('.widget-content').show('slow', function() {
    $(this).addClass('open');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, here was a quick solution
    $('#parent > childNode');
http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

`.children()` http://api.jquery.com/children/

I am not entirely sure if I understand you, but this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.widget-title').click(function() {
 var el = $(this);
 el.addClass('open');siblings('div.widget-content').show('slow',function() {
     //animation complete
 });
});
```

You need to keep the callback function in context using the 'this' keyword which refers to the current DOM element. Otherwise, you'll just be grabbing all DOM elements with a class of widget-title inside your callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you select by a class, jquery will select all the members of that class. Is it possible for you to set an ID or attribute to this specific widget or parent container?